# How to turn the iPhone 4 camera-flash on (and off) 15x a second

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Now this probably seems a little stupid at first, but I am creating a Application to simulate a LCDI (LCD Incapacitator) and I need the iPhone's flash to turn on and off at a frequency of 15 Hz.

I have checked the [Turn on Flash/Torch on iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190034/turn-on-torch-flash-on-iphone-4/3367424#3367424) Thread, but the turning on and off of the flash is quite slow.

My question is more of a brainstorming session, would anyone have any ideas on streamlining the process at which the iPhone turns on the flash? (considering turning it off is one line of code its not the issue.)

Thank you for your help,
Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer to this question on how to turn the flash on (and off) faster:

[How can I make the iPhone 4 LED light fire instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983032/how-can-i-make-the-iphone-4-led-light-fire-instantly)

Comment: I apologize for not finding this earlier, thank you very much.